# how to load datagrid of easyui with json data on click of a button 'search' and how to pass parameter as json object>?

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-easyui

i am trying to load a data grid with json data.I need to load datagrid on form submit.To load data i have to pass form values as json or as model attribute in spring... below is my code

dataGrid code:-

```
$('#search_gridresult').datagrid({
        url:'someurl',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
method:'post',
        fitColumns:true,
        halign:'center',
        columns:[[{
            title:'Sl No.',
            field:'slNo',
            width:100
        },{
            title:'Person Id',
            field:'personId',
            width:100

        },{
            title:'Name',
            field:'userName',
            width:100

        },{
            title:'Email Id',
            field:'emailId',
            width:100

        }]] 
    });
```

function called on click of 'Search' button:--

```
function searchUserResult(){
var str=$('#searchUser').serialize();
$('#search_gridresult').datagrid('load', {  

queryParam:str
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this,

function searchUserResult(){

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'somurl',
      dataType: 'json',
          data:$('#searchUser').serialize(),    
    }).done(function( responseJson ) 
      {
          $('#search_gridresult').datagrid('loadData', responseJson ); 
          });
}
```